# TableViewCell is not clickable with one finger tap, but it is with two fingers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I created a table view and the tableViewCell is not clickable with one finger, but when I try to click the tableViewCell with two fingers the click event takes place. I don't know why this occurres. I created a custom cell in tableView.

## InviteVC

```
import UIKit

class InvitePeopleVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var nameArray = ["Alwin Lazar", "Ajith Ramesh CR", "Ebrahim KK", "Vishnu Prakash"]
    var emailArray = ["alwin@xeoscript.com", "ajith@xeoscript.com", "ebrahim@xeoscript.com", "vishnu@xeoscript.com"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextFld: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegates()
        uiModifications()
        gestureRecognizers()
    }

    func delegates() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        nameTextFld.delegate = self
    }

    func uiModifications() {
        nameTextFld.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Name or email address", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white])
    }

    func gestureRecognizers() {
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(InvitePeopleVC.dismissKeyboard)))
        self.doneImg.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(InvitePeopleVC.doneImgPressed)))
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        nameTextFld.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func doneImgPressed() {
        print("done Image tapped")

    }

    func inviteBtnPressed() {
        print("invite button pressed")
    }

    // UITextFieldDelegate method
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if textField == self.nameTextFld {

            self.nameTextFld.resignFirstResponder()

        }
        return true

    }

    // TableView DataSource methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "InviteCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! InviteCell

        cell.nameLbl.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.emailLbl.text = emailArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    // TableView Delegate methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected row is \(indexPath.row)")
    }



    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

#InviteCell

```
import UIKit

class InviteCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLbl: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

}
```

## UIViewController Images

## TableView Attributes Inspector

[image]

## InviteCell Atribute Inspector

[image]

[image]

In the code above, I'm trying to select a cell with one finger, but the selection does not happen.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: show us real screenshot not design without any elements, try to touch in specific places on cell

Comment: try to remove gesture recognizer from self.view, it seems the parent view takes the touches instead of a table.

Comment: thanks Andrew Veresov

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the following line in your set up code:

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(InvitePeopleVC.dismissKeyboard)))
```

That sets up a gesture recognizer for your whole view and that would swallow any touches on the main view. If you remove that, you should get the table cell selection working correctly :)

Answer (score 10):

A more elegant way of dealing with the tap issue is:

```
          let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AppController.dismissKeyboard))

          view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

          //this is the KEY of the fix
          tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

This way you can keep your gesture recognizer and still get the table view action in one single tap/selection.

Comment: cool this was my issue, But i had added the GR in storyboard and when selecting that in SB I could click the option off cancels touches in view

Comment: this should be the selected answer! Clutch

Answer (score 1):

The Tap gesture you have added in the code is causing the issue. Tapgesture recogniser is listening to the user tap actions in the view. The cell select listner is being blocked by the added Tap gesture.

As @Fahim said, if you remove the tap gesture from your code, then cell selection will work smoothly.