# UITableView's didSelectRow method not working

Tags: uitableview, swift4, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm not receiving the touches. It shows the selection on the iPhone's screen, but it doesn't performs the method `didSelectRow`.

```
    usersTV.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "userCell")
    usersTV.dataSource = self
    usersTV.delegate = self
    usersTV.backgroundColor = .clear
    usersTV.separatorColor = .white
    usersTV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    usersTV.isHidden = true
    usersTV.tableFooterView = UIView()
    usersTV.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    usersTV.isEditing = false
    usersTV.allowsSelection = true
    usersTV.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = false
    usersTV.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    usersTV.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false
    usersTV.delaysContentTouches = false

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

Everything is programatically written.
The cells are custom with 3 labels and added constraints.

What could be the problem ?

UPDATE:

```
class UserCell : UITableViewCell{
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        let viewsDict = ["userName":userName,"field1":field1,"field2":field2]

    contentView.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[userName(120)]-8-[field1]-8-[field2(120)]-8-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    contentView.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[userName]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    contentView.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[field1]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    contentView.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[field2]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
```

UPDATE:
The didSelectRow method works only if you tap with 2 fingers...

Answer (score 1):

[TableViewCell is not clickable with one finger tap, but it is with two fingers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109298/tableviewcell-is-not-clickable-with-one-finger-tap-but-it-is-with-two-fingers)

The answer of this question helped me. I've set GestureRecognizer on the main view. When I remove it the problem fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you.If not,There may be a  issue with the label constraints.

```
@IBOutlet weak var UserTV: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserTV.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "userCell")
    UserTV.dataSource = self
    UserTV.delegate = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let vc :UserCell = self.UserTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell") as! UserCell
    vc.textLabel?.text = "Index: \(indexPath.row)"
    vc.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return vc
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Slected \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: How the constraints are connected with the touch on the cell ? How they can make a problem ?

Comment: I updated the question. Check out!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here is my comment on your code:

- No need to go much complex for this easy task.
- Don't forgot to set delegate and datasource properly.
- No need to use Visual Format way to set constraints, use Anchors.

My suggestion for you:

- Always try to use UICollectionView instead of UITableView.

class SampleTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
// MARK: - Variables
lazy private var listTableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    return tableView
}()

// MARK: - View LifeCycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initialSetup()
}

// MARK: - Private Methods
private func initialSetup() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(listTableView)
    listTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    listTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    listTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    listTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    listTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "listCell")
}

// MARK: - TableView Methods
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Table Row - \(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(#function)
}
```

Comment: I must use my code, because I'm displaying the table view in GameScene. The constraints are set in CustomClassCell: UITableViewCell { override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) { constraints } } I don't have problem with tableView constraints. Obviously the problem is in the constraints of the contentView of the cell.

Comment: Can you share image how actually you want to display your cell?

Comment: `H:|-8-[userName(120)]-8-[field1]-8-[field2(120)]-8-|`

leading, username 120 width, 8 space, field 1, 8 space, field 2 120 width, space 8, trailing